# Is it Possible to spoof browser user agent in Windows XP to get web.whatsapp.com running?

Tags: windows-xp, spoofing, user-agent, whatsapp, web-whatsapp

I am still running Windows XP and want to access whatsapp web ( web.whatsapp.com). Obviously I **cannot** get to the latest and greatest versions of browsers on Windows XP  (Firefox, Chrome, IE and Edge all have EOSC End of software cycle) and this thing intently wants to ensure you have the latest and greatest of OS and browser.

#### What I did:

- Downloaded portable Firefox: Does not run on Windows XP.
- Changed User agent with all perms and combos but it gives me either  unsupported browser OR upgrade chrome version *or* if I say I am Latest Edge on Windows 10 it says the following with a link to a Facebook site:

> “Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."

Is there anything I can do to spoof something to get this to work?

I don’t want to upgrade to Windows 7. It isn’t worth the time and the laptop is a bit oldish for Windows 7.

Other than of spoofing OS and browser string components, how can it detect the spoof?

Comment: Did you ever think that this has nothing to do with spoofing or detection but rather the core capabilities of a browser on Windows XP not being able to do things — such as — deal with modern JavaScript? Look here and see if there is some kind of browser out there that can somehow work on Windows XP with modern websites. [Here](https://xpforever.miraheze.org/wiki/Main_Page) and [here](https://appuals.com/the-5-best-browsers-for-windows-xp/).

Comment: I went through that and already downloaded `otter` before posting this question. when deep down in the settings and change them eventually to spoof WhatsApp bouncer that announced so when so browser is not compatible. my  code could scan successfully but after that there is no  `gui` it just keeps on wanting to load the page I haven't tried the other browsers some of them are Chinese with security issues and the others I'm afraid I may run into the same situation    not sure if there is some some already been tried for the situation and works

Answer (score 4):

You must upgrade your operating system whether you wish to or not. I am posting this from XP Pro using Chrome.

But the highest version of Chrome (using it here) is V49.

Whatsapp requires V60 and that will not run in XP.

So if you wish to run XP, you are limited to what it can do.

If you wish to run modern Apps, you must upgrade.  There is no other alternative.

Comment: Microsoft Edge does not even support Windows XP.  The lowest version of Chromium that Edge is based on is I think 67.  It is not possible to run the latest versions of Firefox and Chromium on WIndows XP.

Comment: At the moment Mypal68  (a FF68 base with security updates) run on XP and can work perfectly with whatsapp web

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to stay with XP, a solution that will work for you is to install
an Android emulator. The emulator will act as an Android phone running on Windows.

The steps to follow are:

- Visit the [Bluestacks website](https://www.bluestacks.com/)
  and download the emulator
- Install the Bluestacks emulator
- Run the emulator and Add your google account
- Find and install the WhatsApp application
- Verify your WhatsApp account
- Enjoy WhatsApp on PC.

For detailed instructions and screenshots see the article
[WhatsApp Free Download for Laptop (Windows 10/8/7/XP)](http://genrontech.com/whatsapp-free-download-for-laptop-pc/).

Comment: which means that I can't use that account on my phone unless I re verify ? can't be using one account on two devices they will not allow it

Comment: @user1874594: If you mean the WhatsApp account, there's no problem.

Comment:  maybe I lost you ... my clear understanding was WhatsApp lets you login one device at a time. so if i use the  `emulator` option  ...  it will validate my account but then I have to take a backup of my chats and restore them on the PC from the phone or is it will have to download about 6gb of data from Google drive ... & and then if I have to use my phone again re verify my account lose my login on emulator

Comment: I'm logged-in to WhatsApp on multiple devices: my actual phone, my old phones and my computer. I never bothered to log off my old phones.

Answer (score 1):

You are lucky, on 2023 as far as you have SP3 on your Windows XP you can use a supported fork (Mypal68) of Firefox 68 that allows to run Whatsapp web.

Though Whatsapp only requires a FF above 60 and Mypal is a 68 Whatsapp detects the "Mypal" string and asks for an upgrade.

Just change the useragent to pretend to be the official FF68.

MyPal
https://github.com/Feodor2/Mypal68/releases

User-Agent Switcher and Manager:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-string-switcher